python3-pyqt3 installed, but no module named "pyqt5" in raspberry pi 5
I have installed "python3-pyqt5" in raspberrypi 5, but when I import PyQt5 in python3, it showed "no module named "pyqt5", shown as following:
what's the problem? And is there anything need to be futhure done?

Show the imports please
